C# WPF binding value turns null sometimes when passed to a IMultiValueConverter
I have a WPF multibinding which uses a converter. Here's some example code (simplified):
<Path.Data>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BoolConverter}">
        <MultiBinding.Bindings>
            <Binding Path="SomeBooleanConditionProperty"
                     Mode="OneWay" />
            <Binding>
                <Binding.Source>
                    <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="8"
                                       RadiusY="8"
                                       Rect="0,0 36,36" />
                </Binding.Source>
            </Binding>
            <Binding>
                <Binding.Source>
                    <Geometry>
                        F1 M 0,36L 18,0L 36,36L 0,36 Z
                    </Geometry>
                </Binding.Source>
            </Binding>
        </MultiBinding.Bindings>
    </MultiBinding>
</Path.Data>

In my converter class (which implements IMultiValueConverter interface) I'm basically checking first binding value (which is boolean), and if it's true, it returns second binding value, otherwise returns third binding value. Here's the code:
public class BoolConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Any(val => val is null))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("One of the bindings values is null");

        return (bool)values[0]
            ? values[1]
            : values[2];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

The problem is: sometimes second or third binding value turns null and I couldn't find why would this happen and what exactly might cause this. Been using this converter on multiple pages and the problem seems to happen only with geometry bindings. For example, binding to a color like this:
<Binding>
    <Binding.Source>
        <Color>
            White
        </Color>
    </Binding.Source>
</Binding>

never caused such problem.
The question is: why would a binding value turn null sometimes when passed to a IMultiValueConverter?

Have you considered using a DataTrigger in a Path Style that sets the Data property?

@Clemens this is also a possible option I will use if the converter issue won't be solved

Another option would be a single Binding with a BooleanToGeometryConverter that has two properties for the the two Geometries.
